# what this conditional means?

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I'm studying a condition and I don't understand because one of the conditionals is set to true by default, without setting a variable before, does anyone tell me what this means?

```
$pagina= Pagina::findOrFail($datos->idpagina);
switch ($datos->tipodato)
{
    case 'logo':
    if(true)  //??
    {
        $datos->logo = urldecode($datos->logo);
        $datos->logo = str_replace(' ', '+', $datos->logo);
        $datos->logo = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,","",$datos->logo);
        $datos->logo = str_replace("data:image/jpg;base64,","",$datos->logo);
        $datos->logo = str_replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","",$datos->logo);
        $pagina->logo =$datos->logo;
    }
    else
    {
        $pagina->logo =$datos->logo;
    }


    $nombreimagen="img".$datos->idpagina.".png";
    file_put_contents(public_path()."/imagenes/{$nombreimagen}",
        base64_decode($datos->logo));
    $pagina->archivologo=$nombreimagen;

    break;
```

Comment: In the case 'logo', the if statement gets executed and the else will never be executed. Unusual/pointless code though it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the code inside the if-statement always be executed and the code inside the else-block will never be.

A common reason is that it once was a condition based on a variable, but a programmer has inactivated it, but kept the else statement to make it easier to restore.

Answer (score 2):

`if (true)` means, that the then case is always executed and you could savely remove the `else` case (and also the condition itself). Mostly this is inserted for debug cases or refactorings and somebody forgot the remove the redundant if condition.